# Force apt to remove all emacs*

Tags: apt, uninstall, emacs

I have a bug-problem with the apt-packages of emacs:

```
>>Error occurred processing debian-ispell.el: File error (("Opening input file" "no such file or directory" "/usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/dictionaries-common/debian-ispell.el"))
>>Error occurred processing ispell.el: File error (("Opening input file" "no such file or directory" "/usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/dictionaries-common/ispell.el"))
>>Error occurred processing flyspell.el: File error (("Opening input file" "no such file or directory" "/usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/dictionaries-common/flyspell.el"))
emacs-install: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/install/dictionaries-common emacs23 failed at /usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-install line 28, <TSORT> line 30.
dpkg: error processing emacs23-lucid (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs:
 emacs depends on emacs23 | emacs23-lucid | emacs23-nox; however:
  Package emacs23 is not installed.
  Package emacs23-lucid which provides emacs23 is not configured yet.
  Package emacs23-nox which provides emacs23 is not installed.
  Package emacs23-lucid is not configured yet.
  Package emacs23-nox is not installed.
dpkg: error processing emacs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs23-lucid
 emacs
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In fact I would be satisfied with just emacs23-nox, a couple of plugins - from apt. But I can neither --purge nor --purge reinstall, nor remove the packages. It always processes until this certain bug.
I did some google-searching, found some stuff on Launchpad suggesting:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge emacsen-common
```

But this is the same... so I hope there a way to tell app to just remove everything releated to emacs, and to start from scratch again?

Thanks,
Marius

Comment: Have you tried to remove the emacs23-lucid ? That is the package causing the error.

Comment: yes, it ends, throwing the same error.

Comment: have you tried using --force-all?

Comment: "sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/emacs23-lucid.postinst" and then "sudo apt-get purge emacs23-lucid"

Comment: hmh, no... doesn't fix my problem. This installs emacs23, and the problem remains the same with a different package.

Comment: dpgk -l ? (list all the packages you have installed. You can use it to see what other emacs you have installed (it won't show dependencies)).  You could also use the software manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the {pre,post}-{installation,removal} script of a package throws errors, sometimes you won't be able to finish installing or remove the package. This can come about either due to a bug in the package (or sometimes another package), in which case you should try to identify the problem and report the bug, or because you've been mucking about inside `/usr`, in which case, well, don't.

The workaround is to either do what it takes to satisfy the package script, or comment out the offending command in the package script. The package script you're having trouble with is located in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/emacs23-lucid.postinst`. The particular command that's failing is `/usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-install ${FLAVOR}`.

The first thing you should try is to fix the underlying problem. Here three files under `/usr/share/emacs23` are missing. They should be symbolic links to the corresponding files under `/usr/share/emacs`. If they are broken symbolic links, try removing them; if the files under `/usr/share/emacs23` don't exist but the files under `/usr/share/emacs` do, try creating the symbolic links.

If you don't manage to fix the problem, either

- comment out the offending line: edit the package script, add a `#` at the beginning of the problematic line(s);
- or ignore the error: add `|| true` at the end of the problematic command, or remove `set -e` near the beginning of the file.

Beyond removing and reinstalling the `emacs23-lucid` package, you may need to reinstall other packages to put your system into a sane state, in particular the `dictionaries-common` package which provides the three troublesome `.el` files.

Answer (score 3):

There are very many unnecessary dependencies linked to Emacs for some reason. My advice is to remove all Launchpad versions of Emacs, Emacsen, and any other flavors of Emacs.

Your next step is to go to gnu.org and download the latest Emacs that is available. You may have to build Emacs before installing it, but what you get from GNU will work without the extra baggage that either Ubuntu, Canonical, or Launchpad requires.

I have other thoughts and opinions on this issue, but I have already gone too far as it is.

Comment: I don't think you've gone too far at all. Go on, tell it like it is!